# EKS Faregate with Rabbit MQ

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

The setup like the following :-

eks with multi AZ (3) and many node group , installed Rabbit MQ , for rabbitmq broker we are using specific node group.

is there any way to force all rabbit mq to be in same AZ and

Comment: You can use a node selector: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by your question because the title says Fargate but then you talk about nodegroups (an EC2 construct). IF you are using Fargate you can control which AZ you are deploying Fargate pods into by creating a Fargate profile that only has the subnets that belong to the specific AZ you want to use. If you use multiple subnets across multiple AZ in your EKS Fargate profile we spread the pods (with a best effort algorithm). If you use one subnet in the Fargate profile we deploy all of them on that subnet.